# The designated data directory /var/lib/mysql/ is unusable. You can remove all files that the server added to it

Tags: mysql, permissions, centos

I am trying to run mysql on centos 7 but this problem occurs. have tried all possible solutions to solve this problem:
removed all files from /var/lib/mysql  rm -rf ./mysql
reinitialized directory mysqld --initialize
chmod -R 777 /var/lib/mysql
chown -R mysql:mysql /var/lib/mysql
chown -R mysql /var/lib/mysql